# How to insert array values into database using laravel

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel

I have group and group members one table is for group where i am storing just group name and second table is group members where i have user_id,group_id field.

I am creating API using postman and i want to insert group members details like this:

`"group_members": [1,3]`

My body request is:

```
{
    "name": "Steve", // name is group name
    "group_members": [1,3]  // [1,3] here 1 and 3 is user_id
}
```

I want to store [1,3] into group_members table in user_id field against group_id if there is [1,3] then two entries should be enter in user_id field
i have also attached the screen shot of my table:

My Controller:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

    try{

        $request->request->add(['created_by' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $group = $this->group->create($request->only($this->group->getModel()->fillable));
        $request->request->add(['group_id' => $group->id]);
        $this->groupMembers->create($request->only($this->groupMembers->getModel()->fillable));

        DB::commit();

        return response([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'Group added',

        ], 200);

    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        return response([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => __('messages.validation_errors'),
            'errors' => $ex->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
    }
```

How i can store this array values into database your help will be highly appreciated?[image]

```
               try {

        $group = $this->group->find($request->input('id'));
        $request->request->add(['updated_by' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $group->fill($request->all())->save();

        return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Group updated'], 500);

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
    }





      public function updateGroup(Request $request)
    {
    $validator = UserValidations::validateGroup($request->all());

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()], 500);
    }

    try {

        $group = $this->group->find($request->input('id'));
        $request->request->add(['updated_by' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $group->fill($request->all())->save();

        return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Group updated'], 500);

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use eloquent relation [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and use the [`attach/sync`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method for save/update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) and a [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

**Group.php**

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'group_members');
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'group_members');
    }
}
```

Now you can add members to a group by their ID simply by doing this:

```
$group = Group::where('name', $request->get('name'))->first();
$group->users()->attach($request->get('group_members', []));
```

The same goes if you like to remove one or more members from a group:

```
$group->users()->detach($request->get('group_members', []));
```

Comment: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::findByName()"

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be `Group::where('name', $request->get('name'))->first()`.

Comment: Method detach not found when i want to remove group members

Comment: It's actually `detach` without a second `t`.

Comment: Okay i see , i will put this code into my update method? i have also edit my code with update method can you please have a look and edit you answer into my code?

Comment: This code is just an example of how to use the attach and detach methods.

Comment: Okay Got it i have one more question? i want to update group and their members against id?

Comment: Against which ID? I don't understand the question.

Comment: against the primary key id i can now attach and detach group members against group name , now i want to update group name and their members , can you suggest any better idea ? i want to update using id ( primary key)

Comment: can we have a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193081/discussion-between-dan-and-syed1234).

Answer (score 0):

Change this two line

```
$request->request->add(['group_id' => $group->id]);
$this->groupMembers->create($request->only($this->groupMembers->getModel()->fillable));
```

To

```
$user_ids = $request->get('group_members');
foreach($user_ids as $user_id){
    $this->groupMembers->create(['group_id' => $group->id, 'user_id'=>$user_id]);
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks it helps me , one more thing , what if i want to update using the same pattern in body request?

Comment: I have also shared the update code where i am just updating name against id please see my edit question

Comment: the code i just shared its for update it is updating only name but i want to update group_members as well  like  i want to update name and group_members i will do name = shahzad and group_members [4,5] from [1,3]

Comment: I have shared the whole update method please have a look

Comment: just like we are adding group and group members in add api , i want to update name and group_members using the same pattern {
 "name": "Steve",
 "group_members": [1,3,4]
}

Comment: Hey @Sohel0415 are u there?

Comment: i think you should go with @Dan suggestions for your later query